# Using codeigniter 4, cannot send link in gmail

Tags: codeigniter, hyperlink, gmail, href

```
$message = "Hi ".$name.", <br>Your account is created successfully. Please click the below link to activate your account
<br><br><a href=".base_url()."/register/activate/".$uniid."Activate now </a>";
```

I already recieved the email but the href function is excluded. it only display
"Hi myname,
Your account is created successfully. Please click the below link to activate your account";

it dont display the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax errors in your code.

1. Missing `>` in anchor tag`".$uniid."Activate now`
2. Wrong `href` dicleration `href=".base_url()."/register/activate/".$uniid."`
3. wrap inner conditions with `'`.

Use below code

```
$message = "Hi {$name}, <br>Your account is created successfully. Please click the below link to activate your account
<br><br><a href='/register/activate/{$uniid}'>Activate now </a>";
```

Comment: niceeee, thank youuuuu ^^